# Flickr API Oauth (node-flickrapi) cache oauth_verifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, flickr

I've been having fun with the authenticated Flickr API via Oauth and have got it working with node.js thanks to the [`node-flickrapi`](https://github.com/Pomax/node-flickrapi) NPM. Each time I run my code the console is telling me to -

```
add the following variables to your environment:
export FLICKR_USER_ID="8443423@N08"
export FLICKR_ACCESS_TOKEN="*****************"
export FLICKR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET="***************"
```

I assume this is to maintain a session and avoid having to keep reentering the `oauth_verifier`.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I want to suppress the web page redirect and having to reenter this code each time I call the service. My code looks like this and otherwise works ok -

```
var Flickr = require("flickrapi"),
    flickrOptions = {
      api_key: "######################",
      secret: "###########"
    };

Flickr.authenticate(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {

    flickr.photos.search({
        api_key: "######################",
        text: "Red, Pandas",
        format: "json",
        content_type : 1,
        per_page : 10
    }, 
    function jsonFlickrApi (err, results) {

        results.photos.photo.forEach(function(photo) {

        var furl = "https://farm" + photo.farm +
                       ".staticflickr.com/" +
                        photo.server + "/" +
                        photo.id + "_" +
                        photo.secret + "_h" + ".jpg";

             flickr.photos.getPerms({
                api_key : "######################",
                photo_id : photo.id
             }, 
             function(err, perms){
                 console.log(perms)
                });

        });

    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, my bad...

answer lies in NPM package `dotenv`.